# Attempt to write to field 'boolean field_name' on a null object reference (Java Android NPE)

Tags: java, android, service

I have a boolean (primitive) field in an android service. I change the value of the field through a method inside the service. The code works all the time except some point which is pretty random it raise null pointer exception mentioning "Attempt to write to field 'boolean field_name' on a null object reference". What could be the possible case as primitive types can't be null in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Revise this field declaration: findViewById(R.id.field_name).
Referring to a field that is not included in the activity will result in this error.

Comment: Its not a view. Its a primitive type boolean field.